# How to pass object to a directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I have a widget which is attached to a resizable directive, i have a highchart placed inside this directive and want to get this chart resized whenever the container is resized. It works well, but when i am using the same directive for different charts, i need to pass the widget id inside the directive.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  plumb-item class="item"    style=" top: 50px; left: 110px; height: 500px; width: 500px; " ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" ng-style="{ 'left':widget.sizeX, 'top':widget.sizeY }"
data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" resizeable  ng-click="resize(widget) >             
    <div  ng-if="widget.type === 'All'" class="box" >
        <div class="box-header"  >                
        <div class="box-header-btns pull-right" style="top:10px" >
        <a title="Data" ng-click="toggleModal(widget)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><a>
        <a title="settings" ng-click="openSettings(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
        <a title="Remove widget" ng-click="remove(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
          <div ng-controller="highchartCtrl">
            <highchart id="widget.id" config="widget.chartConfig"  ></highchart>
                    </div>
         </div>        
     </div>
</div>
```

**Directive :**

```
routerApp.directive('resizeable', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'A', 

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
      $(element).resizable({ 
        resize: function(event, ui) {          
          var chart = $('#chart1').highcharts();            
          height = ui.size.height - 100;
         width = ui.size.width - 40;
          chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = true);

           jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper); 
        }, 
        handles: "all" 

      }); 
    } 
  }; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

identifierchange your HTML to following

```
    <div ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  plumb-item class="item"    style=" top: 50px; left: 110px; height: 500px; width: 500px; " ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" ng-style="{ 'left':widget.sizeX, 'top':widget.sizeY }"
    data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" resizeable  ng-click="resize(widget) >  
...
...
```

And you directive to following

```
routerApp.directive('resizeable', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'A', 

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
    var  widgetId = attrs.identifier;
...
...
```

Comment: attrs is object contains resolved value of all attributes passed in directive.

Comment: any idea how to get sample out of this string using javascript ? "{"text":"Sample"}"

Comment: why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: pass object into directive instead of string. It is much better solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69667/discussion-between-dhavalcengg-and-sajeetharan).